# Monitor Data Consistency of the org

Tags: data

I'd like to set up a control over our data to make sure that our data in the org is correct and if not - know about it before the users reach out to us.

The way I see it - I'd like to have a tool that would allow me to:

1. Perform SOQL Queries with certain intervals(i.e. - every 30 minutes)
2. If the result of the query does not meet a certain criteria - make a callout to an API/send Email Message/send Slack message.
3. (Optional) Show a dashboard with result of the queries from p.1

**Examples of usage**

- Check number of Opportunities without Accounts

  - Daily perform a SOQL Query: SELECT count(Id) FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = null
  - If returned number is more than 0 - make callout, send Email/Slack
- Check that we're under the limit of 100 Scheduled Jobs

  - Every hour perform a SOQL Query: SELECT count(Id) FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Status IN ('Preparing', 'Queued', 'Holding', 'Processing')
  - If returned number is more than 50 - same, make callout, send Email/Slack
- (Ideally) Check that Contract Amount is equal to Opportunity Amount under Account

  - Daily perform 2 SOQL Queries

    - SELECT Amount FROM Opportunity WHERE isClosed = true and Account.Status__c = 'Active'
    - SELECT Amount__c FROM Contract WHERE Account.Status__c = 'Active'
  - For each Account sum up Amount__c of Contract and Amount of Opportunity.
  - If they don't match - notify.
  - The number of records to retrieve might be up to 2kk.

I was looking for a solution that might achieve that, but yet don't see anything quick, simple and low/no-code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: First two: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_subscribe_notify_threshold.htm&type=5 . Third: make a formula field that performs the comparuson, then see the First two comment

Comment: @identigral thanks! Reports could work here, but they have limited capabilities, p3. cannot be done through them. Formulas also have limitations, and some cases could not be covered by them - i.e. if I need to match records by guid, without Lookup. Was looking for a simple solution, somewhat like Excel, that could handle LDV

Comment: Have customers using reports for all 3 scenarios.